# Cocos2d-x CCArray - Objects and Sprites

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new in c++ and cocos2d-x, and I have a problem.
I have a "projectile" it is CCSprite, OK, I insert it in Array:

```
projectile->setTag(2);

_projectiles->addObject(projectile);
```

But when I need it:

```
CCSprite* proj;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(_projectiles,proj){
  CCSprite *projectile = proj;
  ...
```

I have the error about "_projectiles" have CCObject inside.
Sorry for my bad English and thancks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to cast `proj` which is stored in `CCArray` as `CCObject*` to `CCSprite*`:

```
CCSprite *projectile = static_cast<CCSprite*>(proj);
```

You can also you `dynamic_cast` in case you need runtime check that `proj` is actually a `CCSprite`:

```
CCSprite *projectile = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(proj); //will return nullptr if failes to cast
```

Comment: usually I just use C cast, which is (CCSprite*)proj, it has less letters to type :P. maybe I am too lazy.

Comment: @m.ding: you should not use c-style cast when you are able to use C++ casts since they give you a lot of checks and thus help you not to shoot yourself in a leg

Comment: @Andrew:Thanks, I will remember that and use c++ casts in my next projects